# moveit regression? Found empty JointState message

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-indigo, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear List,

Since the last update of indigo (juli 2017) I am getting error messages in move_group with moveit.

For example with moveit-commander, after each "go up" or so, there are 4 lines with

```
[ERROR] [1499944106.195095905]: Found empty JointState message
```

Moveit seems to work however.
It did NOT occur before the last update, and it also occurs in the kinetic version.

Anything I can do?

Regards, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266274/moveit-regression?--found-empty-jointstate-message/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2017-07-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-13**:
NB: in order for errors to show up, you need to format them as *preformatted text*. Use the button with `101010` on it for that.

**Comment by [hvpandya](https://answers.ros.org/users/24274/hvpandya/) on 2017-07-17**:
+1 Observing same issue across three different robots in Kinetic, does not affect the operation for any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that too, but did not find the time to debug it yet.
This is the relevant commit: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/commit/492e8816c5385880a99486765e958a98d11e3df2

To the best of my current knowledge the error message does not change any behavior of the node though, but I'm not 100% sure.

Apparently some code in the `PlanAndExecute` pipeline uses the `RobotStateMsg -> RobotState` conversion tools without checking whether the message is actually filled in.

> Anything I can do?

You could track down *when* and *where* this happens and file an issue on the github project.
That would (hopefully) help a lot.

--- EDIT ---

By now, this should be fixed upstream. See https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/589 .

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As discussed before, this appears to be a regression. I opened a issue as suggested: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/579

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1